# Send GET request and redirect response to browser to download the file

Tags: javascript, request

I have a JavaScript application that uses REST API server as a data provider.

There is one method on API that takes GET request and returns raw response that contains email (as far as I can see there is some kind of .eml content).

I use a simple xmlhttprequest.

The question is: how could I take a response (the file content) and delegate it ti browser so the browser can begin a downloading process ?

Is it possible to do at all with GET method ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not support downloading and saving arbitrary files on a user's computer due to obvious security concerns.

There are, however, a few ways to indirectly trigger the download using javascript. [One of those ways would be using an invisible iframe and setting the source to the path towards the file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749395/2670806)

Answer (score 1):

You might be waiting for browsers to implement `window.saveAs`, see also the question [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)
There are several snipets you could try, for instance https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js or https://gist.github.com/MrSwitch/3552985

Comment: Thank you. Your links helped me. I did use HTML5/Javascript to generate proper href.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have your client running you could use local storage.

to store the item

```
localStorage.setItem('NAME', DATA);
```

and to retrieve

```
localStorage.getItem('NAME');
```

and to delete

```
localStorage.removeItem('NAME');
```

and then set up a callback or promise to render into the html. If you use axios you can set this up with a promise https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios